# recognize bash file with no extension in phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using the last version of PHPStorm, which is 7 I think and want to have file support for files using a pattern such as `*.extension` but those don't have an extension. I tried pattern *, which works, but puts all of my files in bash highlighting.

Does anyone have a solution for that without using the .sh extension?

Edit: 
Bash file are recognize with extension .sh and .bash. It's working nicely, but what I want is to set default file type on files with no extension. If I add .* or * in the list of bash file, all my files are recognize like bash file.
Hope it's more clear, sorry for the probable mistake in my English.

Comment: Check out official plugin documentation: http://www.ansorg-it.com/en/products_bashsupport.html#id1045822. BashSupport should be able to automatically recognize if a file is bash script by looking at the fist line (file contents). Also, can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I also find this issue to be very annoying.  @Plamen - BashSupport will pick up if you have #!/bin/bash in the header of an extensionless script but won't pick up its own default header of #!/usr/bin/env bash, and doesn't offer a way that I know of to change the default header.  To compound issues, BashSupport always adds a ".sh" extension when adding a new bash file.  Many guidelines on non-Windows systems push not using an extension for bash scripts so there should at least be an option to change these things.

Comment: This is a known [issue with BashSupport](https://github.com/jansorg/BashSupport/issues/213), feel free to go there and add your voice.

Answer (score 7):

It may seem weird - but you can try to actually list the files you're using explicitly reading their names.

Not sure of your use-case, but I needed it for git hooks, and there's not so much names for existing git hooks, so it's not that hard to list those :)

For the reference:
Preferences > Editor > File Types > Bourne Again Shell:

[image]